# Is it possible to have a single peer Org in the network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm setting up a little architecture to test some things with Hyperledger Fabric.

Having 3 Orgs, 2 of which formed by just one peer each (availability not the main concern for the test), I'm getting some warning on gossip: can't establish connection with 0.0.0.0:7051, same for both single peers.

```
   2019-10-02 15:18:49.667 UTC [gossip.discovery] func1 -> WARN 02e Could not 
   connect to Endpoint: 127.0.0.1:7051, InternalEndpoint: 127.0.0.1:7051, 
   PKI ID: <nil>, Metadata:  : context deadline exceeded
```

I began to wonder if having just one peer for Org is at least feasable, can't find any example or any guide on how to choose env setting in docker-compose.yaml, or anything that would state that you can't have single peer Orgs.

Any hint?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the docker-compose yaml to the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
warning on gossip: can't establish connection with 0.0.0.0:7051
```

Its because you did not update anchor peer transaction, please do update transaction by providing the anchor.tx

check: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/glossary.html#anchor-peer

Anchor peers are used to establishing cross-organization communication

Command to generate anchorpeer.tx:

```
configtxgen -outputAnchorPeersUpdate anchor_peer_tx.pb -profile SampleSingleMSPChannelV1_1 -asOrg Org1
```

> Output a configuration update transaction to anchor_peer_tx.pb which
>   sets the anchor peers for organization Org1 as defined in profile
>   SampleSingleMSPChannelV1_1 based on configtx.yaml.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it.

What's the best env set for a single peer org?
mfg is the only peer of Org3 and it is anchor.
rmw is the anchor of the other Org on the channel.
`CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=mfg.org3.example.com:11051
CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=rmw.org1.example.com:7051
CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_SKIPHANDSHAKE=true`

Is it correct for mfg configuration?

Comment: Other question: can a Peer be AnchorPeer for more than one Channel?

Comment: Yes, a Peer be AnchorPeer for more than one Channel